# Grep a file for different values in two columns in UNIX

Tags: unix, grep, multiple-columns

I have a feed file from which I want to fetch the rows that just match this criteria below

```
...ABC 123 .....
...BCD 456 ....
```

I did try this and its works fine

```
cat <filename>| grep 'ABC' | grep '123' > Newfile - Create a new file
cat <filename>| grep 'BCD' | grep '456' >> Newfile - Append to the created file
```

But this does not sound like a best way to do it.

is there any better and shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: grep -E 'ABC.*123|BCD.*456'

Comment: it says -E is an illegal option - not sure why -man grep shows -e and -E though

Comment: Which `grep --version` is it?